# Writing text in my content div (in html) makes my background divs move out of place?

Tags: css, html

I'm sure this is some stupid CSS mistake, but in this template website I'm making, whenever I put more than one line of text in the content `div`, it misplaces the two background `div`s on either side of it. Here is the HTML and CSS:
http://pastebin.com/txmQzbx3

I have tried everything I can think of, but I don't know what could be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no such thing as float:center.  If you remove that and change the position value for your content div from relative to absolute, then it works.

http://pastebin.com/B9tXgXYj

Comment: This is a /temporary/ fix, but it still makes adding text extremely hard. As you can see at the link, it's as if it doesn't "recognize" the second div as the border end. Also, I'm trying to avoid setting a constant width, because that makes sizing the browser really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it fixed width then just add `float: left` to the content css
If you want to have it fluid then you'll want to take a look at using the `display: table|table-row|table-cell` css properties to do it

Comment: I tried the float left, but nothing happened. I can't really find anything that the display element would do... Any ideas? Also, one thing that I noticed is that the padding seems to be extending over each div as if it just, isn't there. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: there must be something else effecting because this http://jsfiddle.net/vv4L7/ works how you say you want

Comment: I think its because you defined a width for the content, which I /could/ do. Would setting the background divs from width: 20px to width-min: 20px make them auto size to the browser?

Comment: no, floated block elements will try and be as small as possible, so they would just go to 20px, to get dynamic sides you can put content in use display: table etc like this http://jsfiddle.net/vv4L7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your  backgroundright div above content div,

```
   <div id="backgroundright">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
          <p></p>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This didn't do anything, unfortunately. One thing that I noticed is that the padding seems to be extending over each div as if it just, isn't there. Any ideas as to why this is?